# ThreadPoolExecutor behaving unexpectedly

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I've got a directory of files such as:

```
input_0.data
input_1.data
```

and so forth. I want to parse these files with a function that has been shown to output 47 lines for `input_0.data` when run by itself. However, when I bring a `ThreadPoolExecutor` into the mix and actually run more than one thread, the output from `input_0.data` becomes huge, quickly exceeding the known good 47 lines.

The code I'm trying to use is as follows, with needless details cut fairly obviously:

```
def find_moves(param_list):
    input_filename = param_list[0]
    output_filename = param_list[1]

    print(input_filename+" "+output_filename, flush=True)

    input_file  = open(input_filename, "r")
    output_file = open(output_filename, "w")

    for line in input_file:
        if do_log_line(line):
            log = format_log(line)
            print(log, file=output_file, flush=True)

    input_file.close()
    output_file.close()

if len(argv) != 3:
    print("Usage:\n\tmoves.py [input_dir] [output_dir]")
    quit()

input_files = list()

for file in glob(path.join(argv[1], "input_*.data")):
    input_files.append(file)

input_files = sorted(input_files)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    for file_number, input_filename in enumerate(input_files):
        output_filename = "moves_"+str(file_number)+".csv"
        output_filename = path.join(argv[2], output_filename)
        executor.submit(find_moves, (input_filename, output_filename))
```

It's obvious I'm using this tool incorrectly, but it's not obvious to me where my mistake is. I'd appreciate some guidance in the matter.

It seems like the threads are writing to each other's files, even though they explicitly state they're working on the right file.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. See if you can produce a [mcve]. Check if the problem goes away if you don't write to a file, e.g. just count the output lines or make a list.

Comment: I will see if i can get you that minimal example. I'll adapt it to do just lists, as well, and report back on that.

Comment: Just as a sanity check: did you check for duplicates in `input_files`? Just `pprint.pprint(input_files[:20])` to see.

Comment: Also see if using `Pool.map` instead helps.